# EEPROM stroe and Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, lpc, eeprom

I get warning:

> Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

This is my code:

```
case 4:
{
    uint8_t* adr = 12;
    writeEEPROM((uint8_t *) adr, &z, sizeof(z));
}
```

writeEEPROM have:

```
void writeEEPROM( uint8_t* eeAddress, uint8_t* buffAddress, uint32_t byteCount ){....
```

Where is my problem.

And maybe question 2: it is possible if I send union address into a function writeEEPROM?

Comment: Lokk here `uint8_t* adr = 12;`

Comment: If remove pointer from this line. I get warning 
cast to pointer from integer of different size .... on next line writeEEPROM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the part of the code that makes a pointer from integer without a cast. Change to `uint8_t* adr = (uint8_t*)12;`

> it is possible if I send union address into a function writeEEPROM?

Yes, you can write any kind of data. However, mind struct/union padding and alignment. It is common that the EEPROM has different alignment requirements than RAM variables.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is correct. 
Now I store data in union: 'code' union{
 struct{
  unsigned int  AMPM :24;
 }day; 
}tDay[14];'code'

Now I would like store this union in EEPROM when timer set.